# How to get user name from Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics API and SDK. After logging user in, I would like to display his name. Instead, when I call for user's ad accounts, the API returns just the e-mail without the display name. I'm using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit` scope.

Here's what I'm getting:

```
object(Google_Service_Analytics_Accounts)[86]
  protected 'collection_key' => string 'items' (length=5)
  protected 'internal_gapi_mappings' => ...
  protected 'itemsType' => string 'Google_Service_Analytics_Account' (length=32)
  protected 'itemsDataType' => string 'array' (length=5)
  public 'itemsPerPage' => int 1000
  public 'kind' => string 'analytics#accounts' (length=18)
  public 'nextLink' => null
  public 'previousLink' => null
  public 'startIndex' => int 1
  public 'totalResults' => int 2
  public 'username' => string 'me@gmail.com' (length=12)
  protected 'modelData' => ...
  protected 'processed' => ...
```

How can I obtain user name? Do I need to use some other Google API?

Comment: think the best thing you could do would be to add the userprofile scope to your quests then request the info from the Google+ api   Google analytics api doesn't have access to user name anyplace.

Comment: Yes I thought so. The problem is that the application would need to enable Google Plus API. If it's the only way, I will do it. I will wait for more answers. Please add your comment as the answer, so perhaps we can make it the best answer later :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the Google Analytics API doesn't have access to information about a user beyond there email.

Even if you check [Account users list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/list) it doesn't return the name of the user:

```
 "userRef": {
    "kind": "analytics#userRef",
    "id": "117200475532672775346",
    "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
   },
```

An option would be to add the `profile` scope which is part of the Google+ API. You will then be able to use [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get). Just add `me` as the user id, and it will return profile information for the person that is currently authenticated in:

```
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "117200475532672775346",
 "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Lawton",
  "givenName": "Linda"
 },
```

Or I guess you could take the id from the Analytics account request. They appear to be the same id.